# redirect_uri facebook graph api with cakephp

Tags: facebook-graph-api, cakephp-2.1

I need to share a page from my php website to user's facebook wall. If user is not logged into facebook, my website redirects to the facebook login page using

```
    $user = $facebook->getUser();
    if($user) {
        $result = $facebook->api(
            '/me/feed/',
            'POST',
            array('access_token' => $this->access_token, 'link'=>'google.com', 'message' => 'Test link')
        );
        $this->Session->setFlash('Your link has been succesfully posted on your wall');
        $this->redirect($this->referer());
    }else {
       $login_url_params = array(
          'req_perms' => 'publish_stream',
          'redirect_uri' => 'localhost/pictrail' //thts the same path I gave to my facebook app
       );
       $login_url = $facebook->getLoginUrl($login_url_params);
       header("Location: {$login_url}");
       exit();
    }
```

So, when the user is not logged into facebook .. it redirects to facebook for the user to log in, afterwards it redirects to localhost/pictrail regardless of the url i put in there. I want to redirect it to say localhost/pictrail/images/param ... how can i achieve this? I tried 'localhost/pictrail/images/99' but it didn't work. Everything works fine when the user is logged into facebook.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot redirect from Facebook to `localhost` as it's not a valid address.

The way that I got around this, ***for development***, was to edit my `hosts` file and replace the domain with my local ip.

www.example.com  127.0.0.1

Then you can redirect to www.example.com from your Facebook app and it will render your local development version.

Be sure to add this domain to your local server's vhost or similar.

---

Sorry I misread your question. To change the Facebook redirect url you need to change it in your Facebook app. So you'd have to pass a custom field through to Facebook and then tack it back on afterwards.

Have a look through this, https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/server-side/

Comment: _“You cannot redirect from Facebook to localhost as it's not a valid address.”_ – Not true, you _can_ – _following_ a redirect happens in your browser, and he knows who localhost is.